# How to discover a date or a number near a word - only with regex within regex

Tags: ruby, regex, recursion

I am still learning the intrinsics of regex, and am wondering if it is possible with a single regex to find a number that is at a provided distance from a word.

Consider the following text

```
DateClient
15-01-20130060 15-01-20140010 15-01-20150020
```

I want that my regex matches just `15-01-2013`.

I know I can have the full `DateClient 15-01-2013` with `DateClient\W+\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}`, and then apply a regex afterwards, but i'm trying to build a configurable agnostic system, that gives power to the user, and so I would like to have a single regex expression that just matches `15-01-2013`.

Is this even feasible?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that when you don't follow what is specified in the [regex] tag description, you might receive inapplicable answers.

Comment: Hi @dystroy , didn't quite follow you. What do you mean?

Comment: This : *"Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using"*

Comment: I have updated now. I didn't think it would be relevant, because all i want is a single regex, independently of what i might do afterwards

Comment: The problem is that there is no such thing as a universal regex : different engines have different features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group :

```
DateClient\W+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})
```

Example in javascript (you didn't specify a language) :

```
var str = "DateClient\n15-01-20130060 15-01-20140010 15-01-20150020";
var date = str.match(/DateClient\W+(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})/)[1];
```

EDIT (following the addition of the Ruby tag) :

In Ruby you can use

```
(?<=DateClient\W)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})
```

[Demonstration](http://rubular.com/r/9YfMLop5sh)

Comment: Hi, its ruby...but all i want is a single regex that returns that specific date that is placed at that specific distance from the text

Comment: A regex returns nothing : only a function uses a regex to return something.

Comment: I understand it doesn't, but it does "match" something. All i wanted - perhaps i wasn't clear enough - is a regex that matches "15-01-2013". I will update my question

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your answer is the most complete one, and I will add a plus one to it, and accept it as the correct answer. I only noticed it after going through Bergi's answer. though. Could you explain if a control group would be a better solution than lookbehind, or in which situations should that prevail?

Comment: It really depends on how you use your regex. I personally prefer to choose the simplest regular expression, that's the reason why **I** wouldn't use lookbehind here but simply the capturing group.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I actually used the lookbehind, since this way i can just change my regex from an user interface, instead of acting on the code.

Comment: Guess I will end up using the control group after all...the look-behind has a lot of restritions :-( `Date.{0,20}\W+[\d*\W]*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for matching only the date. However, lookbehind support of your environment can be limited.

Or you could just use a capturing [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), which you will be able to extract from the match result.

Comment: Thank you Bergi I took your answer as the correct one. In the end i ended up with  : `(?<=DateClient\W)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})`

Comment: That combines both solutions :-)

Comment: Sorry, i changed the correct answer to the one that distroy provided, since his answer provided examples. I added a plus one to yours.